# Crash while archiving data by NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety, nskeyedarchiver

My app uses the following function to serialise a set of custom objects (only relevant code is shown):

```
class func serializeShoppingLocations(buyLocations: Set<ShoppingLocation>) -> Data {
    #if os(iOS)
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("ShoppingLocation", for: ShoppingListIOS.ShoppingLocation.self)
    #elseif os(watchOS)
        NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("ShoppingLocation", for: ShoppingListWatch.ShoppingLocation.self)
    #endif  
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: buyLocations)
    return data
}
```

The conditional compilation for the iOS and watchOS targets is required in order to allow both targets to dearchive the serialised data later, even if they have been archived by the other target.

`ShoppingLocation` adopts the `NSCoding` protocol, and inherits from `NSObject`.

This code crashes at the `let data = …` instruction with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

I know that the error probably indicates that a non-existent object is referred. However, the variable `buyLocations` is existent, and I can print the value in the debugger, including all values of the objects in the set.

The stack trace is:
[image]

The stack trace indicates that the archiver starts to archive the `NSSet`, and tries to archive one of the elements of the set, but `setObjectForKey` in the internal mutable dictionary fails.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

During further testing I realised that the crash happens always when at least 2 threads of the app are active.
Particularly, I found a situation where one thread crashed (red in Xcode) at an instruction different from the one mentioned above:

```
let dataBlob = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: shoppingItem.buyLocations)
```

and the other thread stopped at the instruction mentioned above (green in Xcode):

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: buyLocations)
```

Might it be that `NSKeyedArchiver` is not thread-safe?

Comment: make sure ShoppingLocation inherits from NSObject

Comment: @Leo Dabus Thanks for the hint, but ShoppingLocation inherits from NSObject. I will update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem is indeed, as suspected, caused by unsynchronised accesses by multiple threads:

An `NSArchiver` walks through an object graph, starting at the root object, and archives on the way every object it encounters.
In order to create a correct archive, it is therefore required that the object graph is not mutated until the archiver terminates.

In a single-threaded application, this is guaranteed automatically.
In a multi-threaded application where more than 1 thread can mutate the object graph, the programmer is responsible to ensure this, because the archiver has no way to prevent other threads to mutate the root object. (If, e.g., the archiver would first make a deep copy of the object graph, and then archive the copy, the object graph could be mutated during the deep copy).

It is therefore required to serialise all get and set accesses to the object graph, e.g. by execute them in a serial access queue.

Comment: let archivedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: recentCalls as NSArray)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(archivedObject, forKey: recentCalls)
 defaults.synchronize()
I'm using like these to save my data in UserDefaults for my model array but at this time app crashes only on iPhone 7 due to memory issue. It takes around 800 MB or more memory for this archiving process and crashes. Can you please provide any solution for this how to prevent memory issue and crash??? @Reinhard Manner